# SQL command to clear specific text

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to run a SQL command that reads * from my database but I need it to seek specific text in the email field and return a null if it doesn't equal. Example, I'm trying to filter out all emails in our database that are not internal email addresses, so it would need to filter out any that don't have our company name in it.

I was able to filter this with a LIKE command, but it just simply ignores the rest of the fields in the results. I know access has the IIf(InStr command, so I'm hoping there is something similar in SQL

Comment: Post the actual code you have tried, and we'll tell you where it's gone wrong.

Comment: `USE Server
SELECT firstName AS EmployeeFirstname, lastName AS EmployeeLastname, title AS EmployeeTitle, id AS EmployeeID, emailAddress AS EmployeeEmailAddress
FROM db.Information
WHERE ISNUMERIC(id)<> 0 AND empStatus = 'A'`  
I have tried to do `, IIf(InStr([emailAddress],"companyname")=0,"",[emailaddress]) AS EmployeeEmail` but that seems to only work in Access

Comment: @SpookyFries edit that into your original post.

Comment: Agree with @alroc, Spooky. Will make the question clearer and much more useful once answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand, but something like this may work for you.

```
USE Server 
SELECT 
  firstName AS EmployeeFirstname
, lastName AS EmployeeLastname
, title AS EmployeeTitle
, id AS EmployeeID
, 
  Case 
  When emailAddress Like '%@mycompany.com' 
      Then  emailAddress
  Else Null
  End AS EmployeeEmailAddress 
FROM db.Information 
WHERE ISNUMERIC(id)<> 0 
  AND empStatus = 'A'
```

So what this will do is give you the rows regardless of what email they have (still taking into account your other selections of  ISNUMERIC(id)<> 0  AND empStatus = 'A'). But in those rows, if the email is your company they would display and if not the field would be Null. Obviously change the “mycompany.com” it the Like to whatever string you actually need to search for,

Comment: This looks more like what I'm looking for! I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude all records where the company is not in the email address, add

```
 where 
       emailAddress not like '%companyname%'
```

If you want to blank out the non-company email addresses, you can use `case`

```
Select
     case when emailaddress not like '%company%' then null else emailaddress end
```

Comment: I don't want to simply exclude the records, I just want to clear the email address and turn it into `NULL` or empty in my output. Now I don't want to actually clear the email addresses from the database, just from the finished report which I'm exporting to CSV